# Connecting to Test Container with Postgres Fails

Tags: postgresql, docker, scala, testcontainers

For one of my project, I'm using the Test Containers set up. What I do here is basically create a Postgres image like this:

```
# To build this Dockerfile run the folloing command
# docker build -t custom-postgres-initdb --build-arg SQL_SCRIPT_PATH=/path/to/your/sql-script.sql .

# Use the official PostgreSQL image as the base image
FROM postgres:latest

# Create a directory to store your SQL scripts and set it as the working directory
WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

# Copy all SQL scripts from the specified directory into the container
COPY *.sql ./

# Set the environment variable for the initial password
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_pass

# Optionally, you can set other environment variables like POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_DB
ENV POSTGRES_USER=my_user
ENV POSTGRES_DB=my_db

# You can also specify the port to expose (default is 5432)
EXPOSE 5432

# Any additional configuration or scripts can be added here if needed

# Start PostgreSQL
CMD ["postgres"]
```

I build this docker file and produce the image on my local machine. I then have my web application where I would like to use Test Containers and I have the following implementation:

```
  override val container: PostgreSQLContainer = PostgreSQLContainer().configure { psqlContainer =>
    psqlContainer.setDockerImageName("my-postgres-test-container:latest")
    psqlContainer.withDatabaseName(s"${dbConfig.dbName}")
    psqlContainer.withUsername(s"${dbConfig.user}")
    psqlContainer.withPassword(s"${dbConfig.pass}")
    psqlContainer.withExposedPorts(5432)
    psqlContainer.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd =>
      cmd.withHostConfig(
        new HostConfig().withPortBindings(
          new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(dbConfig.port), new ExposedPort(32852))
        )
      )
    )
    //psqlContainer.waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*database system is ready to accept connections.*", 2))
  }

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    container.start()
    someProvisioningRepoImpl.map(_ => new ProvisioningRepoImpl[IO](getDBConfigForTestContainer))
  }
```

When I run my unit tests which should actually start this container image, I get the following:

```
2023-09-18 03:24:15.583 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2023-09-18 03:24:15.689 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-09-18 03:24:15.689 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-09-18 03:24:15.689 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-09-18 03:24:15.689 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-09-18 03:24:15.691 UTC [72] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-09-18 03:24:15 UTC
2023-09-18 03:24:15.694 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
[info] com.myproj.repository.impl.ProvisioningRepoImplSpec *** ABORTED ***
[info]   org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed for image my-postgres-test-container:latest
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:361)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:334)
[info]   at com.dimafeng.testcontainers.SingleContainer.start(Container.scala:48)
[info]   at com.myproj.repository.impl.ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.beforeAll(ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.scala:37)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)
[info]   at com.myproj.repository.impl.ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.run(ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.scala:15)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework.org$scalatest$tools$Framework$$runSuite(Framework.scala:318)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:513)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
[info]   at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:346)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:334)
[info]   at com.dimafeng.testcontainers.SingleContainer.start(Container.scala:48)
[info]   at com.myproj.repository.impl.ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.beforeAll(ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.scala:37)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)
[info]   at com.myproj.repository.impl.ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.run(ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.scala:15)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework.org$scalatest$tools$Framework$$runSuite(Framework.scala:318)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:565)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:356)
[info]   at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:346)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:334)
[info]   at com.dimafeng.testcontainers.SingleContainer.start(Container.scala:48)
[info]   at com.myproj.repository.impl.ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.beforeAll(ProvisioningRepoImplSpec.scala:37)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
[info]   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException: Lambda expression in org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer: expected the predicate to return <true> but it returned <false> for input of <InspectContainerResponse(args=[postgres, -c, fsync=off], config=ContainerConfig(attachStderr=false, attachStdin=false, attachStdout=false, cmd=[postgres, -c, fsync=off], domainName=, entrypoint=[docker-entrypoint.sh], env=[POSTGRES_USER=my_user, POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_pass, POSTGRES_DB=my_db, PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin, GOSU_VERSION=1.16, LANG=en_US.utf8, PG_MAJOR=16, PG_VERSION=16.0-1.pgdg120+1, PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data], exposedPorts=[5432/tcp], hostName=1911373f892d, image=my-postgres-test-container:latest, labels={org.testcontainers=true, org.testcontainers.lang=java, org.testcontainers.sessionId=81430d2b-e76b-40ad-9573-7c1384b0e702, org.testcontainers.version=1.19.0}, macAddress=null, networkDisabled=null, onBuild=null, stdinOpen=false, portSpecs=null, stdInOnce=false, tty=false, user=, volumes={/var/lib/postgresql/data={}}, workingDir=/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, healthCheck=null), created=2023-09-18T03:24:14.278565359Z, driver=overlay2, execDriver=null, hostConfig=HostConfig(binds=[], blkioWeight=0, blkioWeightDevice=null, blkioDeviceReadBps=null, blkioDeviceWriteBps=null, blkioDeviceReadIOps=null, blkioDeviceWriteIOps=null, memorySwappiness=null, nanoCPUs=0, capAdd=null, capDrop=null, containerIDFile=, cpuPeriod=0, cpuRealtimePeriod=0, cpuRealtimeRuntime=0, cpuShares=0, cpuQuota=0, cpusetCpus=, cpusetMems=, devices=null, deviceCgroupRules=null, deviceRequests=null, diskQuota=null, dns=null, dnsOptions=null, dnsSearch=null, extraHosts=null, groupAdd=null, ipcMode=shareable, cgroup=, links=[], logConfig=LogConfig(type=json-file, config={}), lxcConf=null, memory=0, memorySwap=0, memoryReservation=0, kernelMemory=null, networkMode=default, oomKillDisable=false, init=null, autoRemove=false, oomScoreAdj=0, portBindings={32852/tcp=[Lcom.github.dockerjava.api.model.Ports$Binding;@68ad7ec1}, privileged=false, publishAllPorts=false, readonlyRootfs=false, restartPolicy=no, ulimits=null, cpuCount=0, cpuPercent=0, ioMaximumIOps=0, ioMaximumBandwidth=0, volumesFrom=null, mounts=null, pidMode=, isolation=null, securityOpts=null, storageOpt=null, cgroupParent=, volumeDriver=, shmSize=67108864, pidsLimit=null, runtime=runc, tmpFs=null, utSMode=, usernsMode=, sysctls=null, consoleSize=[0, 0], cgroupnsMode=host), hostnamePath=/var/lib/docker/containers/1911373f892dce0ddf1fcf26b482a03f28f99c02c69256dfba24df755e8ac129/hostname, hostsPath=/var/lib/docker/containers/1911373f892dce0ddf1fcf26b482a03f28f99c02c69256dfba24df755e8ac129/hosts, logPath=/var/lib/docker/containers/1911373f892dce0ddf1fcf26b482a03f28f99c02c69256dfba24df755e8ac129/1911373f892dce0ddf1fcf26b482a03f28f99c02c69256dfba24df755e8ac129-json.log, id=1911373f892dce0ddf1fcf26b482a03f28f99c02c69256dfba24df755e8ac129, sizeRootFs=null, imageId=sha256:fd28b74a1c6089bc16843b3253dd3620e114d58d4bb0b3a0dce6a5b651477e73, mountLabel=, name=/strange_jones, restartCount=0, networkSettings=NetworkSettings(bridge=, sandboxId=68ca67cb4eec28cfd39fcc2e89d7b8b58d76925b1918d906e4ca797c3988fa84, hairpinMode=false, linkLocalIPv6Address=, linkLocalIPv6PrefixLen=0, ports={5432/tcp=null}, sandboxKey=/var/run/docker/netns/68ca67cb4eec, secondaryIPAddresses=null, secondaryIPv6Addresses=null, endpointID=0c5f9dc1e6a099c230c6f0d6cb2ec44371f30e188a62c07aca4712f833a5a535, gateway=172.17.0.1, portMapping=null, globalIPv6Address=, globalIPv6PrefixLen=0, ipAddress=172.17.0.3, ipPrefixLen=16, ipV6Gateway=, macAddress=02:42:ac:11:00:03, networks={bridge=ContainerNetwork(ipamConfig=null, links=[], aliases=null, networkID=1b2b1a0837af2951fba3404b22f0a7e33a65397902228bf396207328f27fef5c, endpointId=0c5f9dc1e6a099c230c6f0d6cb2ec44371f30e188a62c07aca4712f833a5a535, gateway=172.17.0.1, ipAddress=172.17.0.3, ipPrefixLen=16, ipV6Gateway=, globalIPv6Address=, globalIPv6PrefixLen=0, macAddress=02:42:ac:11:00:03)}), path=docker-entrypoint.sh, processLabel=, resolvConfPath=/var/lib/docker/containers/1911373f892dce0ddf1fcf26b482a03f28f99c02c69256dfba24df755e8ac129/resolv.conf, execIds=null, state=InspectContainerResponse.ContainerState(status=running, running=true, paused=false, restarting=false, oomKilled=false, dead=false, pid=1000163, exitCode=0, error=, startedAt=2023-09-18T03:24:14.557232613Z, finishedAt=0001-01-01T00:00:00Z, health=null), volumes=null, volumesRW=null, node=null, mounts=[InspectContainerResponse.Mount(name=4a8888d89cc56f2a677f5766e932a612e0235310834600f381a369ea926da63b, source=/var/lib/docker/volumes/4a8888d89cc56f2a677f5766e932a612e0235310834600f381a369ea926da63b/_data, destination=/var/lib/postgresql/data, driver=local, mode=, rw=true)], graphDriver=GraphDriver(name=overlay2, data=GraphData(rootDir=null, deviceId=null, deviceName=null, deviceSize=null, dir=null)), platform=linux)> within 5 seconds.
[info]   at org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.core.ConditionAwaiter.await(ConditionAwaiter.java:167)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.core.AbstractHamcrestCondition.await(AbstractHamcrestCondition.java:86)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.core.ConditionFactory.until(ConditionFactory.java:985)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.core.ConditionFactory.until(ConditionFactory.java:691)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.core.ConditionFactory.until(ConditionFactory.java:708)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:467)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:356)
[info]   at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:346)
[info]   at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:334)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: In the shared log, you have a message saying `database system is shut down` before the test. Not sure if that could be the cause. If you are using the new API, here you have an [example for setting up postgresql in your IT test](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-scala/blob/38bcd33700442169e20a065f1f85f6b51348efe5/docs/src/main/tut/usage.md#postgresql). Then you can use the [start/stop hooks provideds by testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-scala/blob/38bcd33700442169e20a065f1f85f6b51348efe5/docs/src/main/tut/usage.md#startstop-hooks)

Comment: If the shared links in my previous comment are not enough, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With that level of details is hard to guess where the error could come from

Comment: I will give it a try and post the results shortly!

Comment: Yes, that helped. What is the mistake that I did with my implementation above?

Comment: The provided example is not enough to understand what you did wrong. Not sure what exactly you change. Edit your post and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You shouldn't need to provide `EXPOSE` or `CMD` in your derived file, and it's possible the `CMD` is causing a problem.  Hard-coding passwords as `ENV` where `docker history` can easily retrieve them isn't usually a best practice either.  Can you use the unmodified `postgres` image, with environment-variable and bind-mount settings to provide the configuration and initialization scripts?

Comment: Would you provide an answer?

Comment: It would be also better to check default PostgreSQL containers' `CMD` or `Entrypoint`, and edit your image. Also, is your container is in detached mode? Without further information it is hard to evaluate.